# consulta sql, contar por compañia telefonica

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una estructura de db de la siguiente forma:, una db llamada pruebas, y una tabla llamada tblusuarios

```
 - id INT usuario VARCHAR(20),
 - usuario VARCHAR(20), 
 - nombre VARCHAR(20), 
 - sexo VARCHAR(1),
 - nivel    TINYINT,
 - email VARCHAR(50),
 - telefono VARCHAR(20),
 - marca VARCHAR(20), 
 - compañia VARCHAR(20),
 - saldo FLOAT,
 - activo BOOLEAN
```

No se hacer la consulta siguiente:

> Contar el número de usuarios por compañía telefónica

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TBLUSUARIOS WHERE
```

Comment: serías tan amable de mostrar que has intentado?

Comment: no sé como cogerlo, no se ese tramo de por compañia

Comment: has investigado sobre group by?, puedes editar y colocar lo que lleves aunque este incompleto o mal

Comment: sería así? SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TBLUSUARIOS GROUP BY compania ?

Comment: Te recomendaría que evites el uso de caracteres como `ñ` o vocales acentuadas para dar nombre a tablas o columnas. Si ocurre algún problema de codificación las consultas se crearán erróneamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Usa una función de agregación `COUNT()` para contar las coincidencias por el nombre de la compañia ya que es el dato que buscas identificar
- Usa `GROUP BY` para poder agrupar los datos por alguna regla
- A la operación con la función `COUNT` asignale un alias

Lo anterior contará todas las compañias coincidentes, las agrupará y las ordenará por el nombre de dicha compañía

Necesitas agrupar los datos ya que las funciones de agregación solo devuelven un campo calculado; entonces al agrupar te mostrará en n renglones los grupos que coinciden por nombre

Finalmente tu código debería ser así

```
SELECT compañia, COUNT(compañia) AS PorCompañia
FROM pruebas
GROUP BY compañia
ORDER BY compañia;
```